# Keycloak lost admin password

Tags: keycloak

I have a local test installation of keycloak 12 and unfortunately I've lost the admin password, any idea on how to reset it or reset the keycloak configuration without losing the realms ?

I already used add-user cli command to add a user but even with that one I can't access

Comment: is this the command you tried? `sudo -u keycloak ./bin/add-user-keycloak.sh --user YourUser --password YourNewPass --realm YourRealm`

Comment: Yes, but I didn't pass the realm since I don't know which one is. I try with Master and master without success return an error saying realm don't exists. Without Realm the account is created but I can't login.

Comment: oh I think you need to know your realm, might not be possible otherwise

Answer (score 11):

For me, I had to find the user in the user_entity table. Then delete rows in related tables. After this, I restarted the pod, and the admin user login became the one passed through the environment variables KEYCLOAK_USER and KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD.

Find the user id

```
select * from user_entity
```

Delete rows

```
delete from credential where user_id = '<user-id>';
delete from user_role_mapping where user_id = '<user-id>';
delete from user_entity where id = '<user-id>';
```

Comment: Also needed to run 

delete from user_required_action where user_id = 'user_id';

Comment: In my case admin user was not reset even though i did the same. And even worse,  at that time  i can't know the admin role because i deleted it. i have no other choice to do. i would rather  give another man or woman the admin role  by changing db.

Answer (score 10):

The Keycloak's admin user is created only during the first initialization of the container image. Once it's created, the environment variable KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD has no effect. When restarting the pod you can see in the initialization logs:

```
16:16:35,881 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) KC-SERVICES0104: Not creating user admin. It already exists.
```

To create a new admin user you should delete the current one in the database. Or just change the admin username to admin_bkp if you prefer. After this, just restart the container and the admin user is created again.

Connect to the database

```
$ kubectl exec -it keycloak-database-bd94f668c-rvmbt -- bashbash-5.1$ psql $ keycloak -U postgre -W
```

Delete or update the current admin user:

```
psql (12.10)
Type "help" for help.
keycloak=# update  user_entity set "username"='admin_bkp' where "username"='admin';
UPDATE 1
```

Delete the application pod

```
$ kubectl delete pod keycloak-database-bd94f668c-rvmbt
```

Now you should be able to log in using the admin user passed through the environment variables KEYCLOAK_USER and KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD

Comment: `kubectl exec -it KEYCLOAK_DB_POD -- bash -c "psql keycloak -U postgres -W"`

Comment: If you want to do it cleaner, you have to also delete related records in tables "credentials" and "user_role_mapping"

Comment: this is slick!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Keycloak Docker image, you can get admin crendential using docker inspect:

```
docker inspect <keycloak_container_id>
```

then search for Config > Env, you will find KEYCLOAK_USER and KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD.

Comment: Caveat with this is that if you've changed the password, Keycloak won't reset it to what's in KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD.

Comment: dont know but worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the solutions given in the answers above but still not getting it, thanks to the previous answers, though. I arrived at the following workaround: **promoting an existing user to admin**

Keycloak is configured with MySQL,

Before I deleted the admin entries, I noticed a listing for role-mappings:

```
select * from user_role_mapping;
```

| ROLE_ID | USER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 43d3c162-f9c1-48d1-ac76-e8b231bdcfa5 | 333b12de-2463-4a3b-819e-1b72a5769523 |
| e1779c28-b09f-4fda-8795-e76598004563 | 333b12de-2463-4a3b-819e-1b72a5769523 |
| 43d3c162-f9c1-48d1-ac76-e8b231bdcfa5 | c4576081-e20d-473b-93ff-f43068fee722 |
| **a5c63fd3-20de-4596-9ed7-cea440d29384** | **c4576081-e20d-473b-93ff-f43068fee722** |

The last two USER_ID's (`c4576081-e20d-473b-93ff-f43068fee722`) refer to the admin's. The last ROLE_ID `a5c63fd3-20de-4596-9ed7-cea440d29384` is the admin role, so I create an entry for the user `333b12de-2463-4a3b-819e-1b72a5769523` like so:

```
insert into user_role_mapping (ROLE_ID, USER_ID) values("a5c63fd3-20de-4596-9ed7-cea440d29384", "333b12de-2463-4a3b-819e-1b72a5769523");
```

I then log in with the username of the promoted user, I find server state intact, including my registered clients.

Other reference:
[Recommendation from Keycloak Discourse Community](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/how-to-reset-admin-password-on-keycloak-local-instance/14300)

Best regards